# React Fetch api fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch from randomuser.me, my component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RandomUser extends Component {
    state = {
        contacts:[]
    }

    async   componentDidMount(){
        const url = 'http://api.randomuser.me?results=20';
        const response = await fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'});
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
    }

    render(){
    console.log(this.state.contacts);
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Users:</h2>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default RandomUser;
```

The error I see in console is:

[image]

`Access to fetch at 'http://api.randomuser.me/?results=20' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

How do I correct it? I'm not using any local server and relying on randomuser.me

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Try it without setting the mode in the fetch.  I also have a React project using the randomuser API, I just `await fetch(url)` and that has always worked.

Comment: @Quentin `function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin...` from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_request_options

Comment: @Quentin also working here https://jamessouth.github.io/directory/ with code `let response = await fetch(url);`